# Unable to get content in plain text from notes and attachment file

Tags: apex, soql

```
Attachment att=[Select Body From Attachment where id='00P7F00000F8EQs'];
string stringvalue = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.body);
blob blobvalue =EncodingUtil.base64Decode(ss);
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, it's hard to tell exactly what your problem is because you haven't included enough detail. Generally speaking, the more details you can provide, the better. The body of an `Attachment` should already be encoded in base64, so it's not clear what you would be trying to encode it again. You should [edit] your question to include more details (other approaches you've tried, a portion of the value of `Body` at each step of your processing, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `toString();`

```
Attachment att=[Select Body From Attachment where id='00P7F00000F8EQs'];
string stringvalue = att.Body.toString();
```

Test class:

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(Name='demo.txt' , Body = Blob.valueOf('My Text') , parentId='0012600000rTz4t');

insert att;

System.assertEquals('My Text',[SELECT ID , BODY FROM Attachment where Id=: att.Id][0].Body.toString());
```

Comment: I have already tried this , It gives error System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

Comment: what error? I just tried and it works. Given that your file is txt file.

Comment: I have the file as docx

Comment: docx file is not a text file but a binary file, you cant read in SF. You have written as Plain Text file in the description.

Comment: Thanks @Pranay Jaiswal now its working.